# How to make color for UIToolbar the same as keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, keyboard, uitoolbar

I have issue with UIToolbar background color above the keyboard, here the picture: [not expected background color on UIToolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suUEJ.png). I expected to see the same color as keyboard background, what I'm doing wrong?

I have this code:

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                  target:nil action:nil]; // to make close button on right side
UIBarButtonItem *closeBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemClose
                                  target:self action:@selector(endEditing:)];
toolbar.items = @[spaceBarButton, closeBarButton];
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Answer (score 4):

So It seems I found solution its kinda hack, but still working.

UIInputView on init have **inputViewStyle** which mimics the keyboard background. If use UIInputView as parent view for UIToolbar with a clear background color, we will be good. **Or use UIInputView itself**, and add  buttons on it, and apply it on inputAccessoryView without UIToolbar.

It depends on your content and future needs.

Example of keyboard what will shows: [toolbar with right color implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJuW.png)

My example with UIToolbar as subclass you can implement variant you want:

```
//add toolbar
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar sizeToFit];//get height for toolbar
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;//set width for toolbar
CGRect frame = toolbar.frame;
frame.size.width = width;
toolbar.frame = frame;

//toolbar buttons setting
UIBarButtonItem *spaceBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                   target:nil action:nil]; // to make close button on right side
UIBarButtonItem *closeBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemClose
                                   target:textField action:@selector(endEditing:)];
toolbar.items = @[spaceBarButton, closeBarButton];

//make toolbar background clear color
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
         forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//creating UIInputView for using its background color
UIInputView *inputView = [[UIInputView alloc] initWithFrame:toolbar.bounds inputViewStyle:UIInputViewStyleKeyboard];
// UIInputViewStyleKeyboard - view mimics the keyboard background
[inputView addSubview:toolbar];
textField.inputAccessoryView = inputView;
```